# Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\alpha(x) = -\lim_{x \to \infty^-}\alpha(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Let $\alpha(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x(1+t^2)^{-1}dt$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\alpha(x) = -\lim_{x \to \infty^-}\alpha(x)$.

I don't understand what is the difference between $x \to \infty$ and $x \to \infty^-$. I would think they are equal.

Comment: Maybe they mean $x$ approaching $\infty$ and $-\infty$? Which would make sense, seeing as though the integral is $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: Note that $\alpha(x)$ is an odd function (this is possible to prove without actually evaluating the integral) and hence $\alpha(-x) = -\alpha(x)$ and your limit is valid for any odd function. Also I think you need to write $x \to -\infty$ instead of $x \to \infty^{-}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\int (1+t^2)^{-1}dt=\arctan(t)$.

$x\to \infty$ (x to positive infinity) and $x \to \infty^-$ (x to negative infinity)